# How can I create a List of numbers or strings association with Micronaut Data JDBC?

Tags: java, micronaut, micronaut-data

I would like to do something similar as with Spring Boot JPA

```java
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name = "timeseries_security_categories", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "timeseries_id"))
@Column(name = "security_categories_integer")
private Set<Integer> securityCategories = new HashSet<>();
```

How can I do this with Micronaut Data JDBC?

## I've also tried a work around, but I cannot get it to work either

I'm not sure if this is possible with Micronaut Data yet, however I also tried a workaround where I created a mapped entity. But I cannot get this to work either

Timeseries class

```java
@MappedEntity(value = "timeseries")
public class Timeseries {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Relation(value = Relation.Kind.ONE_TO_MANY, mappedBy = "timeseries")
    private Set<TimeseriesSecurityCategory> securityCategories = new HashSet<>();

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Timeseries setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
        return this;
    }

    public Set<TimeseriesSecurityCategory> getSecurityCategories() {
        return securityCategories;
    }

    public Timeseries setSecurityCategories(Set<TimeseriesSecurityCategory> securityCategories) {
        this.securityCategories = securityCategories;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Timeseries Security Category association

```java
@MappedEntity(value = "timeseries_security_categories")
@Serdeable
@Introspected
public class TimeseriesSecurityCategory {

    @MappedProperty("timeseries_id")
    @Relation(value = Relation.Kind.MANY_TO_ONE)
    private Timeseries timeseries;

    @MappedProperty("security_categories_integer")
    private Integer value;

    public Timeseries getTimeseries() {
        return timeseries;
    }

    public Integer getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public TimeseriesSecurityCategory setTimeseries(Timeseries t) {
        this.timeseries = t;
        return this;
    }

    public TimeseriesSecurityCategory setValue(Integer value) {
        this.value = value;
        return this;
    }

}
```

And the repository

```java
@JdbcRepository(dialect = Dialect.POSTGRES)
@Join(value = "securityCategories", type = Join.Type.LEFT_FETCH)
public abstract class TimeseriesRepository implements CrudRepository<Timeseries, Long> {

    private final JdbcOperations jdbcOperations;

    public TimeseriesRepository(JdbcOperations jdbcOperations) {
        this.jdbcOperations = jdbcOperations;
    }

    public abstract Collection<Timeseries> list();

}
```

The list method generates a valid SQL, however the returned collection of securityCategory is always empty. Like it cannot bind the association to the timeseries.
The generated SQL:

```sql
SELECT timeseries_."id",
       timeseries_security_categories_."timeseries_id" AS security_categories_timeseries_id,
       timeseries_security_categories_."security_categories_integer" AS security_categories_security_categories_integer
FROM "timeseries" timeseries_
    LEFT JOIN "timeseries_security_categories" timeseries_security_categories_ ON timeseries_."id"=timeseries_security_categories_."timeseries_id"
```